# JavaScript in HTML - Unable to use Radio Buttons Values to display Conditional Result

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I would like to do this quiz "Buzzfeed Style" where i choose certain answers, and based on what I've chosen I receive a certain artist to listen to. I am trying to do this right now by using an HTML form and JavaScript. I cannot get the results to show. I have included the JavaScript and HTML I am working with below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var season = 0;
var activity = 0;
var meal = 0;
var vacation = 0;
var total = 0;

function displayResult() { 
    season = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "season"]:checked').value);

    activity = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "activity"]:checked').value);

    meal = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "meal"]:checked').value);

    vacation = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "vacation"]:checked').value);

    total = season + activity + meal + vacation;

    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = total;

        if (total < 4) {document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = "You got Taylor Swift."; } 
        else if (total >= 4 && total < 7) {document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = "You got Justin Bieber."; }
        else if (total >= 7) {document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = "You got Maroon 5."; } 
        else {alert("Fill out all questions before submitting."); }
    return false; }
window.onload = function () {document.getElementById("form1").onclick = displayResult; };
```

```html
<!--Quiz-->
<div id="main">
  <div id="header1">
    <h1>Which <span id="solo">SOLO</span> PENGUIN RECORDS artist should you listen to?</h1>
  </div>

  <form id="form1" action="#">
    <p>What is your favorite season?</p>
    <td>
      <tr>
        <p class="rb">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="season" id="summer" value="0" />
            <span>Summer</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p class="rb">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="season" id="fall" value="1" >
            <span>Fall</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p class="rb">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="season" id="winter" value="2" >
            <span>Winter</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p class="rb">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="season" id="spring" value="3" >
            <span>Spring</span>
          </label>
        </p>
      </tr>
    </td>


    <p>Where would you prefer to spend your Saturday Morning?</p>
    <td>
      <tr>
        <p class="rb">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="activity" id="gym" value="1" />
            <span>The gym</span>
            </label>
        </p>

        <p class="rb">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="activity" id="bed" value="3" />
            <span>In bed</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p class="rb">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="activity" id="coffee" value="2" />
            <span>Coffee Shop</span>
          </label>
        </p>
      </tr>
    </td>

    <p>What is your favorite meal of the day</p>
    <td>
      <tr>
        <p class="rb">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="meal" id="bfast" value="0" />
            <span>Breakfast</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p class="rb">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="meal" id="brunch" value="1" />
            <span>Brunch</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p class="rb">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="meal" id="lunch" value="2" />
            <span>Lunch</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p class="rb">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="meal" id="dinner" value="3" />
            <span>Dinner</span>
          </label>
        </p>
      </tr>
    </td>

    <p>Where is your dream vacation destination?</p>
    <td>
      <tr>
        <p class="rb">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="vacation" id="island" value="1" />
            <span>Tropical Island</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p class="rb">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="vacation" id="Mountains" value="2" />
            <span>Mountainside</span>
          </label>
        </p>
        <p class="rb">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="vacation" id="City" value="3" />
            <span>Bustling City</span>
          </label>
        </p>
      </tr>
    </td>

    <br/><br/>
    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light black" type="submit" name="action" id="submitForm" value="submit" onSubmit="algorithm.js">Submit</button>
  </form>

  <p id="answer"></p>
  <p id="answer2"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You're missing `=` after `window.onload`.

Comment: Is that in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: Wasn't a copying error, added it to my code, but still couldn't get the answer to display. Any other thoughts?

Comment: You have no condition after the second `else if`. Aren't you seeing console errors when you try to run the code?

Comment: Yes, I added the else if edit and made further edits based on the console (apologies for not vetting it further before post). I am still unable to get the answer to show.

Comment: When you click on a radio button, it's also a click on the form, so the `displayResult` functin runs immediately. You should add a button to click on instead of clicking on the form.

Comment: it works now! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

In your way you should take the season, activity, meal and vacation from URL parameters (`?season=0&activity=1&meal=0&vacation=1&action=submit#`), and not directly form radiobox, because you are using `<form>` and `onSubmit`.

If you want an asyncronously behavior and get the result directly from the radioboxes, you can remove `<form>` and the submit button, and use this code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function () {

        Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("input")).map((elem) => {

            elem.addEventListener('change', () => {

            season = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "season"]:checked').value);

            activity = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "activity"]:checked').value);

            meal = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "meal"]:checked').value);

            vacation = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "vacation"]:checked').value);

            total = season + activity + meal + vacation;

            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = total;

            if (total < 4) {document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = "You got Taylor Swift."; } 
            else if (total >= 4 && total < 7) {document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = "You got Justin Bieber."; }
            else if (total >= 7) {document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = "You got Maroon 5."; } 
            else {alert("Fill out all questions before submitting."); }

            return false;

            });
        }); 

})();
```